# Are carbon nanotubes and graphene very flammable?

Tags: combustion, carbon-allotropes

The reason I ask is because carbon is quite flammable in virtually every shape we encounter in nature. Even diamonds burn as a matter of fact. And after I just saw some steel wool burn easily, I started wondering about graphene and the likes. I mean, it is still a sheet, but it doesn't get thinner than a single atom, right? So in terms of surface area, this would be almost ideal for any form of oxidation. And since it is only 1 atom thick, I suspect it all wants to burn up rather quickly.

Does anyone know about this? Have experiments been conducted?

Edit: Steel Wool.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by very flammable. It is much more flammable than carbon forms with less surface/volume ratio, but much less flammable like many powdered organic matter able to form flammable gases.

Comment: Since graphene is usually adhered to a surface, that would greatly change its properties, including flammability.  BTW, "steel wool" is likely the metal wire "sponge" to which you referred. Even more flammable: cotton wool, used as an applicator for cosmetics. Pull some apart to increase surface area, and when ignited and dropped, most will be consumed before hitting the floor. [Of course, do this in a *concrete* or *ceramic tile* floored room.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Pippik. Thanks for the 'Steel Wool' part. Updated post accordingly. And regarding the substrate onto which graphene may be applied; yes, sure this is a completely different scenario. It's like saying Hydrogen is not dangerous in a closed box without oxygen, if you're getting my drift.